# Spring initializr project: Roadmap?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-initializr

We want to run our own instance of the [Spring Initializr](https://github.com/spring-io/initializr) and enhance it with own modules. However there is still no stable version available: Spring Inititializr's current version is still `1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and it is not available on Maven central. Moreover, there have been some major changes in the module structure some weeks ago, which makes building and maintaining from source difficult...

My questions: is there a roadmap for the Spring Initializr project? When will it be available on Maven central?

Comment: I guess never as it isn't intended to be released like that (afaik). If you want your own, fork it and make the modifications you need.

Comment: You might consider a project template system like lazybones (https://github.com/pledbrook/lazybones)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Initializr works in a continous deployment mode with no release scheduled at the moment. Every time we push a change on master, the whole tests suite is ran and if it passes we deploy the new version to production.

We did a quiet `0.1.0.RELEASE` on `repo.spring.io` because a project requires it but we have no intention to go `1.0.0.RELEASE` on Maven central at the moment. Part of the reasoning is that Spring Initializr is a service and not a library and we want to have the freedom to make breaking changes if necessary.

We do have some plans for an official release but nothing scheduled.